# Swapping desktops (unintentionally) on Mavericks

Tags: macos, desktop, mission-control

I am using OSX Mavericks 10.9.2 and I have 4 desktops that I use in my daily workflow. From time to time Desktop 2 and Desktop 3 switch places and I cannot figure why. Probably when moving from desktop to desktop (sometimes I use 3 finger swap and sometimes Control^#) I activate some shortcut.

Does anybody what is shortcut for swapping desktops or some other explanation for this? And how to disable it :)

Thanks

Comment: Does http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104900/is-there-any-way-to-save-the-order-of-spaces-in-mission-control help (assuming you mean Spaces when you say Desktop)?

Comment: @patrix It does speak on same topic but it does not help. Since I have already made my assignment to specific desktop (space) all works as intended. Until desktops swap places. I am new to Mac so in Mission Control I see name 'Desktop 1', 'Desktop 2' ... probably older alias is Space so I think we mean the same thing.

Comment: Have a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104912/9058, is the 2nd option set or unset on your Mac?

Comment: Thank you! This is solution, if you like you can answer and I will accept. I would not mark it as duplicate since it much more "google-able" in current form.

Comment: Closing will keep it indexed by Google and reference the other question as well.